# Android emulator not working after installing ia32-libs on 64-Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, 64-bit, ubuntu-12.04, x86

I've 64-bit eclipse installed on a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. The android SDK and ADT is installed correctly and I'm able to execute applications on my android device. But, when I'm trying to boot the emulator, it freezes. How do I overcome this problem? Thanks.